# How to disconnect the loading massage to the content when the app is fully loaded

Tags: r, shiny

For the code below, I would like to delay the disappearance of the loading message without increasing the sys.sleep. How can do this? Below please see my server code.

Best,
Nader

```
    library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Test"),
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "
                           #loadmessage {
                           position: fixed;
                           top: 0px;
                           left: 0px;
                           width: 100%;
                           padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                           text-align: center;
                           font-weight: bold;
                           font-size: 100%;
                           color: #000000;
                           background-color: #CCFF66;
                           z-index: 105;
                           }
                           ")),
      numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
      conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                       tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage"))
    ),
    mainPanel(shinyjs::useShinyjs(), plotOutput('plot'))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
      Sys.sleep(2)
shinyjs::hide("loadmessage")
       hist(runif(input$n)) 
      
     
      })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `hide()` the panel with `{shinyjs}` once you're done with loading:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Test"),
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "
                           #loadmessage {
                           position: fixed;
                           top: 0px;
                           left: 0px;
                           width: 100%;
                           padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
                           text-align: center;
                           font-weight: bold;
                           font-size: 100%;
                           color: #000000;
                           background-color: #CCFF66;
                           z-index: 105;
                           }
                           ")),
      numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
      conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                       tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage"))
    ),
    mainPanel(shinyjs::useShinyjs(), plotOutput('plot'))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
      Sys.sleep(2)
      my_plot <- hist(runif(input$n)) 
      shinyjs::hide("loadmessage")
      my_plot
      })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to delay the disappearance of the loading message without changing Sys.sleep?

Comment: If you store the plot in a variable you can hide the panel after building the plot and just before returning it, See my edit